# Creating a new file with group permissions

Tags: c++, linux, fedora

This seems straight forward enough , but i have not been able to identify how i could achive this in C++.

I am creating a file as

```
ofstream logfile(LOG_FILE, ios::out | ios::app);
```

The file is created with the following permissions.

```
-rw-r--r--
```

What i really want is

```
-rw-rw-rw-
```

For obvious reasons , i do not want to change the system umask for the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the chmod call. This is used to change the permissions of a file.

Comment: This would be the shell command :| or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to set the file permissions with standard C++. I suggest you use the [`chmod()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod) system call, or equivalent if running on a non-unix OS.

Answer (score 1):

## include

mode_t  mode=00777;
chmod("operate.sh", mode);